# Nest JS's Throttler Guard from REST module is breaking GraphQL module

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, graphql, nestjs

I have a [Nest.js](https://nestjs.com/) app with a REST module and a GraphQL module. Both are imported into an `App.module.ts`. I'm using Nest's [Throttler Guard](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/rate-limiting) to protect the whole application. As it's already known, [GraphQL does not work with the normal `ThrottlerGuard`](https://github.com/nestjs/throttler/issues/574), so I created a [`GqlThrottlerGuard`](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/rate-limiting#graphql) and imported it on the GraphQL module, while importing the original `ThrottlerGuard` on the REST module.

So, my graphQL module looks like this:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      autoSchemaFile: true
    }),
    ThrottlerModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => ({
        ttl: config.get('security.throttle.ttl'),
        limit: config.get('security.throttle.limit'),
      }),
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: GqlThrottlerGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class GraphModule { }
```

And the REST module, like this:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ThrottlerModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => ({
        ttl: config.get('security.throttle.ttl'),
        limit: config.get('security.throttle.limit'),
      }),
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [RestController],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: ThrottlerGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class RestModule implements NestModule {}
```

Finally, both modules are imported to the App Module, which is the module I actually run:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    RestModule,
    GraphModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

For some reason, the error seen [here](https://github.com/nestjs/throttler/issues/574) is still happening to me on the `GraphModule`, even though the normal `ThrottlerGuard` is imported only on the RestModule. Should it work like this? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 5):

`APP_GUARD` is a **global** binding, it applies to **all** routes. You should make one coherent guard that returns the proper request response based on the `ExecutionContext#getType` method which will either return `http` or `graphql`

```js
@Injectable()
export class CustomThrottlerGuard extends ThrottlerGuard {

  getRequestResponse(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const reqType = context.getType<ContextType | 'graphql'>()
    if (reqType === 'graphql') {
      const gqlCtx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
      const ctx = gqlCtx.getContext();
      return { req: ctx.req, res: ctx.res };
    } else if (reqType === 'http') {
      return {
        req: context.switchToHttp().getRequest(),
        res: context.switchToHttp().getResponse()
      }
    } else {
      // handle rpc and ws if you have them, otherwise ignore and make previous `else if` just an `else`
    }
  }
```